# SELECT CAST CASE Statement

Tags: sql

This is my currently working statement:
*SELECT code, description FROM table WHERE filter1 = 'Style' AND filter2 IN ('$EDIT#FI_ASSET_CODE$') OR filter2 IN ('$PROJECT#PROJECT_Standard$') ORDER BY sortorder*

Now, I need to include an IF:

**IF ('$EDIT#RN_SCOPE$') = 'Project'** then my select statement should be:
*SELECT code, description FROM table WHERE filter1 = 'Style' AND filter2 IN ('$EDIT#FI_ASSET_CODE$')ORDER BY sortorder*

**IF ('$EDIT#RN_SCOPE$') = 'Standard'** then my select statement should be:
*SELECT code, description FROM table WHERE filter1 = 'Style' AND filter2 IN ('$PROJECT#PROJECT_Standard$') ORDER BY sortorder*

Can someone help me in writing the SELECT CAST9CASE WHEN statement?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT code, description 
FROM table 
WHERE filter1 = 'Style' AND 
   filter2 IN (
   case 
    when ('$EDIT#RN_SCOPE$') = 'Project' then '$EDIT#FI_ASSET_CODE$'
    when ('$EDIT#RN_SCOPE$') = 'Standard' then '$PROJECT#PROJECT_Standard$'
   end)
ORDER BY sortorder
```